# Web View Dynamic height issue in Swift

Tags: swift, webview

I'm loading data in web view from a url coming from api response.
I want web view to get height as according to content size of url data. But it isn't working fine.

[image: This is how my screen looks when I set constraints]

I have made outlet for my web view height constraint and pass height to that from javascript function. This is my code how I load url and make it dynamic,

```
func loadWeb(webURL: String) {
    self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.headerView.center
    self.activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.whiteLarge
    self.headerView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
    self.showActivityIndicator(show: true)

    let url = URL(string: webURL)
    self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    self.showActivityIndicator(show: false)
    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                self.webViewHeight.constant = height as! CGFloat
            })
        }
    })
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Start to load")
    showActivityIndicator(show: true)
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.hideIndicator), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("finish to load")
        self.showActivityIndicator(show: false)
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

It is not getting the perfect height as url load in `WebView`. How to get that.

Comment: Facing the same issue in webview. Might be Wkwebview will work. Not yet implemented.